# How to transform a timestamp in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

I have following Dataframe

```
df1:
col1 col2 timestamp
0    4    1512712800000
1    6    1512712800000
2    4    1518510600000
3    8    1512712800000
4    9    1518510600000
```

I want to convert the timestamp like this

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1518485400000")/1000)

>>>>2018-02-13 02:30:00
```

and save it as a new column in the dataframe

So it should look like this

```
df1:
col1 col2 timestamp       Date
0    4    1512712800000   2018-02-13 02:30:00
1    6    1512712800000   2018-02-13 04:30:00
2    4    1518510600000   2018-02-13 01:35:00
3    8    1512712800000   2018-02-13 08:30:00
4    9    1518510600000   2018-02-13 09:30:00
```

then i tried to do it in that way

```
df1['Date'] = (datetime.fromtimestamp(int(df1.timestamp)/1000))
```

but I get a compile error. What's the problem, how can i fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api1.py", line 59, in <module>
    dfnew4['Date'] = (datetime.fromtimestamp(int(dfnew3.timestamp)/1000))
  File "/Users/Blueshift/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 97, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2], 'timestamp': ['1512712800000','1512713800000']})

print df

#    col      timestamp
# 0    1  1512712800000
# 1    2  1512713800000


convDate = lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000)

df['date'] = df['timestamp'].apply(convDate)

print df

#    col      timestamp                date
# 0    1  1512712800000 2017-12-08 06:00:00
# 1    2  1512713800000 2017-12-08 06:16:40
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
df1["Date"] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000) for x in df1["timestamp"]]
```

Full code I used to recreate your example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[0,1,2,3,4],
                   "col2":[4,6,4,8,9],
                   "timestamp":["1512712800000","1512712800000","1518510600000","1512712800000","1518510600000"]})
df1["Date"] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000) for x in df1["timestamp"]]
print (df1)
```

The output is this:
   `col1  col2      timestamp                Date
0     0     4  1512712800000 2017-12-08 07:00:00
1     1     6  1512712800000 2017-12-08 07:00:00
2     2     4  1518510600000 2018-02-13 09:30:00
3     3     8  1512712800000 2017-12-08 07:00:00
4     4     9  1518510600000 2018-02-13 09:30:00`